# Can not add edges to an empty graph

Tags: python, python-3.x, igraph

I try to create an empty graph and add some edges which I retrieve from a data frame like this:

```
edgelist = []
for i in range(len(edges)):
    edge = (int(edges.loc[i, 'source']), int(edges.loc[i, 'target']))
    if edge not in edgelist:
        edgelist.append(edge)
```

The edge list looks okay

`[(0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 2), (0, 3), (2, 3), (2, 4), (3, 4)]`

Then I create an empty graph and try to add edges:

```
G = ig.Graph()
G.add_edges(edgelist)
```

And it throws an error

`Error at type_indexededgelist.c:272: cannot add edges, Invalid vertex id`

What can be wrong with vertex id?
I've tried to make ids start from `1` but it throws this error again.

Comment: You need to add vertices first, as documented. E.g. `g.add_vertices(5)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add vertics before you connect them with edges.

Try this:

```
edgelist =[(0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 2), (0, 3), (2, 3), (2, 4), (3, 4)]

v_list=[]
for edge in edgelist:
    for v in edge:  
        if v not in v_list:
            v_list.append(v)

g.add_vertices(len(v_list))
```

And then:

```
G.add_edges(edgelist)
```